# Dynamically Apply Attributes to DOM elements in ngRepeat in Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a `dropdown-menu` directive in angular and had an idea.

Is there anyway that I can `extend` a "list" of `attributes` to a DOM element within an `nr-repeat`?

```
<li ng-repeat="item in menuItems" ng-init="extend((current_element).attributes, item.attributes)" />
```

**My only problem is that I do not know how to get what I refferred to as the `current_element` above.** It may even be better to just pass the `current_element` to a function:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in menuItems" ng-init="attributeExtend(current_element, item)" />
```

To be more descriptive, say I have an array:

```
var menuItems = [
    {
        label: "One"
        attributes: {
            style: "background-color: blue"
        }
    },
    {
        label: "Two"
        attributes: {
            style: "background-color: red"
        }
    },
    {
        label: "Three"
        attributes: {
            style: "background-color: green"
        }
    }
];
```

..which I am using for my `ng-repeat`.

Now, once I enter my function called by my `ng-init`:

```
<!--HTML-->
    <li class="upper-li" ng-repeat="item in menuItems" ng-init="extend(current_element, item, $index)" />

<!--SCRIPT-->
    scope.extend = function(elem, item, $index)
    {
        /*
            elem should be equal to:

                $element.find('li.upper-li')[0].children[$index]

            ..which I've discovered I can use as a work around,
            but I am still looking for my answer...
        */

        for(var key in item.attributes)
        {
            elem.setAttribute(key, item.attributes[key]);
        }
    }
```

I just want a better way of doing this. Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do to the attributes exactly? What is the final outcome you want?

Comment: use directive and access $element and add $attr

Comment: I am trying to access the current `element` getting created by the `ng-repeat` on `ng-init`. In other words, I want `ng-init` to return the current element (`current_element`)

Answer (score 1):

The possible and easy way to `extend` attributes of an DOM element is to dynamically create you dropdown list with items inside a directive.

```
 .directive("dropdown", function() {
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var data = scope[attrs["dropdown"]];
        if (angular.isArray(data)) {
          var listElem = angular.element("<select>");
          element.append(listElem);
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var option = angular.element('<option>'); 
            for(var key in data[i].attributes)
            {
                option.attr(key, data[i].attributes[key])
            }
            listElem.append(option.text(data[i].label));
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/pj8QedIpbyUZVYyopQ5R

Comment: ugh.. yes, this works, but I tend to try and avoid doing DOM element creation/manipulation through Javascript whenever I can, at least when I am using Angular. Still a valid answer though. +1